# navigator.camera.getpicture allowEdit not working in Android when taking photo

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

The option to crop image is not working after taking a photo and selecting photo using Photos option.

But its working fine when selecting a photo from Gallery option.

Here is the code

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 10,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        allowEdit: true
});
```

Comment: Does the same code work fine if tried from a pure cordova project?

Comment: Specify your Worklight/MobileFirst version and answer Vivin's question.

Comment: @Vivin: Same code works fine in cordova project. But not in worklight.

Comment: @Idan Adar: Version - 7.1.0.00-20160401-2103

Answer (score 0):

The following is written in the GitHub README:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

**allowEdit is unpredictable on Android** and it should not be used! The Android implementation of this plugin tries to find and use an application on the user's device to do image cropping. The plugin has no control over what application the user selects to perform the image cropping and it is very possible that the user could choose an incompatible option and cause the plugin to fail. This sometimes works because most devices come with an application that handles cropping in a way that is compatible with this plugin (Google Plus Photos), but it is unwise to rely on that being the case. If image editing is essential to your application, consider seeking a third party library or plugin that provides its own image editing utility for a more robust solution.